# PostgreSQL: Select data with a like on timestamp field

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sql-like

I am trying to select data from a table, using a "like" on date field "date_checked" (timestamp). But I have this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone
```

My request is :

```
SELECT my_table.id
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.date_checker LIKE '2011-01-%'
```

I don't want to use :

```
SELECT my_table.id
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.date_checker >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00' 
    AND  my_table.date_checker < '2011-02-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's all very well not "wanting to use" < and > with timestamps, but those operators can be converted into index scans, and a string-match... well, it can, but EWWWW.

Well, the error is occurring because you need to explicitly convert the timestamp to a string before using a string operation on it, e.g.:

```
date_checker::text LIKE '2011-01-%'
```

and I *suppose* you could then create an index on `(date_checker::text)` and that expression would become an index scan but.... EWWWW.

Comment: I think if index scans are you primary concern, you'd probably have a better change with the `LIKE` approach.  The selectivity estimations of inequalities can fall down pretty quickly.  Just saying ... ;-)

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use ::varchar?

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
SELECT my_table.id
FROM my_table
WHERE CAST(my_table.date_checker AS VARCHAR) LIKE '2011-01-%';
```

Comment: Easy, I liked this one.

Comment: That's the sane response to the question..

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the `date_trunc` function would be more to your liking:

```
... WHERE date_trunc('month', my_table.date_checker) = '2011-01-01'
```

You can also put an index on that expression, if needed.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to do a comparison on some part of a `timestamp`, it's far better to use the [`EXTRACT()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function. For example:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_checker) = 2011
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_checker) = 1
```

Details of the different "fields" you can extract from a date are in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Comment: or date_trunc if you need something like the first x part of a date.  you can turn '2011-01-13 12:15:23' into '2011-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: Docs for the function suggested by Scott: [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) (Postgres 12)

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can do a `like` on a date column without converting it to a string representation first.

You can use the between query to select between two dates, for instance:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE date_checker BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01';
```

Comment: It's possible to do a like on a date column

Comment: @KevinCampion: No it's not. Not without converting it first.