# Php postgresql search query

Tags: php, postgresql, search

I am not sure if I am doing the query right but i am just a beginner in PHP and postgresql hence my code.

what i am trying to accomplish is a search using date picker which will give data from a date:

```
<?php
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

    $query = ("SELECT trees.tree_type,tree_solds.transaction_id,tree_solds.actual_height,tree_solds.selling_height,tree_solds.sub_total,transactions.date_purchased FROM tree_solds
                                                    left join trees on tree_solds.tree_id = trees.id
                                                    left join transactions on transactions.id = tree_solds.transaction_id
                                                    WHERE date_purchased LIKE $searchq ");


                                        $result = pg_query($query); 
                                        if (!$result) { 
                                            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
                                            echo pg_last_error(); 
                                            exit(); 
                                        } 


                        $count = pg_num_rows($result);
                        if ($count == 0) {
                            $output = 'No Data on that date!';
                        } else {
                            while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                               $output .= printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", htmlspecialchars($myrow['transaction_id']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['date_purchased']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['tree_type']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['actual_height']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['selling_height']), number_format($myrow['sub_total'], 2));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

HTML form

```
 <form action="location4.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" class="span2" name="search" value="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dp2">

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </form>
 <?php print("$output");?>
```

Keep getting this error and no result.

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   timestamp without time zone ~~ integer LINE 4: ... WHERE
>   date_purchased LIKE 2014-... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given
>   name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmastool/location4.php on line 50 Problem
>   with query SELECT
>   trees.tree_type,tree_solds.transaction_id,tree_solds.actual_height,tree_solds.selling_height,tree_solds.sub_total,transactions.date_purchased FROM tree_solds left join trees on tree_solds.tree_id = trees.id left
>   join transactions on transactions.id = tree_solds.transaction_id WHERE
>   date_purchased LIKE 2014-12-07  ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   timestamp without time zone ~~ integer LINE 4: ... WHERE
>   date_purchased LIKE 2014-... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given
>   name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Do you want to match timestamps considering dates and ignoring hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: just matching the date i what i am after without the hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this: `WHERE date_purchased LIKE '%$searchq%'` if you want just a part of it.

If you want exact match then `WHERE date_purchased = '$searchq'`

**NOTE:** `%` is a joker character in the `LIKE`, check the manual how to use.

Comment: added the '%$searchq%' but still got an error almost same as the other one

it showed the result WHERE date_purchased LIKE '%2014-12-07%' as part of the error.

Comment: What is the type of `date_purchased` column?

Comment: date_purchased is a timestamp

Comment: Then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799615/postgresql-select-data-with-a-like-on-timestamp-field

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pg_query_params('SELECT ... WHERE DATE_TRUNC('day', date_purchased) = $1', array($searchq))
```

See [the documentation for details. You should **always** make sure that query parameters are properly escaped (i.e. not concatenated verbatim to the query) to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue due to the tip of polka_bolka.

```
 WHERE TO_CHAR(date_purchased, 'yyyy-mm-dd') LIKE '%$searchq%' ")
```

converted the date_purchased to char.

```
<?php
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

    $query = ("SELECT trees.tree_type,tree_solds.transaction_id,tree_solds.actual_height,tree_solds.selling_height,tree_solds.sub_total,transactions.date_purchased FROM tree_solds
                                                    left join trees on tree_solds.tree_id = trees.id
                                                    left join transactions on transactions.id = tree_solds.transaction_id
                                                    WHERE TO_CHAR(date_purchased, 'yyyy-mm-dd') LIKE '%$searchq%' ");


                                        $result = pg_query($query); 
                                        if (!$result) { 
                                            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
                                            echo pg_last_error(); 
                                            exit(); 
                                        } 


                        $count = pg_num_rows($result);
                        if ($count == 0) {
                            $output = 'No Data on that date!';
                        } else {
                            while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                               $output .= printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", htmlspecialchars($row['transaction_id']), htmlspecialchars($row['date_purchased']), htmlspecialchars($row['tree_type']), htmlspecialchars($row['actual_height']), htmlspecialchars($row['selling_height']), number_format($row['sub_total'], 2));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```